# Is the CIFS driver user-mode or kernel-mode?

Tags: linux, cifs

Fact: Linux lets you mount CIFS file shares.

Question: Is the CIFS driver an in-kernel driver? Or is it a user-mode FUSE driver or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a CIFS driver [in the kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/cifs), but there are also FUSE drivers capable of mounting CIFS shares: `fusesmb`, [SMBNetFS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smbnetfs/), perhaps others.

If you mount shares using `mount -t cifs`, you’re using the kernel driver; if you mount shares through your desktop environment (*e.g.* by browsing to them in GNOME Files), you might be using a FUSE driver instead.

Comment: `mount -t cifs` is exactly what I'm doing.