# How can i mount a directory without sudo permission

Tags: linux, mount

```
// mount samba directory
sudo mount -t cifs //$host/$path $mountpath -o username=$user,noauto,user,uid=1001,gid=1002,forceuid,forcegid
```

```
//mount remote ftp
echo $key | sshfs $user@$host: $mount -C -p $port -o idmap=user -o password_stdin
```

The first command I have to perform by using sudo privilege, otherwise `mount.cifs: permission denied: no match for XXXX found in /etc/fstab` prompted.

However, second command that i issue can be success without using sudo privilege.

1. Both commands are mounting remote directory to linux file systems, but why behave different?
2. I thought mount action need to be performed by privilege user to ensure security policy, am I misunderstanding any ?
3. Can a user mount file while no sudo privilege permission given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a specific filesystem.

sshfs is FUSE (filesystem in userspace) and does not require superuser privileges.

CIFS is a kernel module, and requires root.
See: [Is the CIFS driver user-mode or kernel-mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630014/is-the-cifs-driver-user-mode-or-kernel-mode)

If you want to mount `cifs` shares as a regular user, use `sudo`.
See: [What sudoer spec allows users to mount cifs shares?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/what-sudoer-spec-allows-users-to-mount-cifs-shares)

There is also `fuse-nfs`
https://github.com/sahlberg/fuse-nfs